# CSS Positioning "Error" in IE, Firefox

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, css-position

I'm fairly new to HTML/CSS, so this might be a fairly simple fix. I'm designing/coding my company's new site (outofboundscreative.com/inprogress/index.html), and I've run into what I believe to be the final snag in my CSS for cross-browser support. In Safari, Chrome and Opera, the copyright segment in the footer is positioned correctly using top: 10px; However, when I look at the page in either IE or Firefox, it displaces it 10px more than what is wanted/needed, which then pushes the div nearly out of view. I know that each browser uses positioning: and display: a little differently, but this one legitimately has me stumped. When I make one change, it looks great in IE/Firefox, but then shoves the div up into the table's area. Any suggestions? Thanks for your help in advance.

For reference, here's the offending code:

```
footer {
left: 0;
clear: both;
width: 100%;
height: 55px;
bottom: 0px;
cursor: default;
display: block;
z-index: 1000;
overflow: hidden;
position: fixed;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.9);
}

#footer-line-left {
top: 20px;
right: 50%;
float: left;
clear: both;
width: 1000%;
height: 2px;
position: absolute;
margin-right: 220px;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

#footer-line-right {
top: 20px;
left: 50%;
float: left;
clear: both;
width: 1000%;
height: 2px;
position: absolute;
margin-left: 220px;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

table, tr, th {
top: 5px;
z-index: 1000;
position: relative;
font-size: 10pt;
text-align: center;
font-style: italic;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: Baskerville, "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", serif;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

#copyright {
top: 10px;
color: #444;
clear: both;
width: 100%;
display: block;
position: relative;
font-size: 11px;
font-style: normal;
text-align: center;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your p tag you need to add margin and padding:

```
<div id="copyright">
p {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I knew it was something simple. Thank you much!